# How do I create a backup save?

Tags: soma

I'm a few hours in to SOMA, and I'd really like to go back and see some things from earlier levels again.  However, it seems that they only let you save one file in this game!

I found my game's save data in `C:\Users\[USER]\Documents\my games\Soma\Main`.  There's a bunch of random characters in these file names though, and I don't want to corrupt my current file by making a bad backup.  How should I go about doing it so I can play a few levels and then come back to my save later?

Comment: I think it stores all of the autosaves. I don't know what random characters are you talking about - it's just location and date. You can rename them also - I tested it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If that's the save file you found, all you need to do is copy and paste it into the same folder. You'll want to rename it (e.g., add a "1" to the end) so it won't mess with anything. Then to use the backup, rename it by taking the "1" off and rename the current save by adding a "1". This is usually how usable backups are stored for things.

Comment: Have you tested this with this particular game?  I believe there are Steam cloud interactions, so it might not work the same way.

Comment: @Chase Game saves are always saved to your computer and also uploaded to the cloud. If your save game file is named differently from the one in the cloud, you can choose which to use. There shouldn't be a problem in doing it this way.